# Is there end-of-life date for Magento 2.1.x?

Tags: upgrade

I just received email saying that there's an update for 2.1.x > 2.1.10. There are also updates for 2.0.x and 2.2.x.

Is there end-of-life date for Magento 2.1.x? Do they plan to develop 2.0.x, 2.1.x and 2.2.x in parallel?

I'm wondering whether to upgrade from 2.1.9 to 2.2.1 or just keep updating to next versions of 2.1.x - when available.

Answer (score -2):

Go for 2.2.1 if possible to keep code as much up to date as possible. There are tons of bugs fixed. The sooner you will start the upgrade the less tears you will shed

Comment: I'd agree if not for the fact that I've nearly finished migrating modules from 1.x to 2.1.9 and now I'm reading that 2.2.x [is not fully backwards-compatible](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html). Hence my preference would be to keep current project in 2.1.9 and start new ones in 2.2.x - providing that 2.1.x will be maintained.

Comment: That is true but from my experience if you stay at lower version you will get a huge chance to stuck there forever. And so far it is relatively easy to upgrade.

Comment: sorry man but this is not the proper answer for Alan's question. Actually, I was asking myself too if 2.1 will have a long term support. I didn't found anything on the internet except this thread.